# Chatbot text preprocessing necessary on each input?

Tags: nlp, chatbot

I'm trying to learn about NLP and Chatbots.
From what i've read, text preprocessing (e.g. lowercaseing and turn numbers to words) is done on the training data in order to train the model. I'd think, that this is also necessary on each input a user makes, in order to find an appropriate response later, but I can't find any sources confirming this.

Is the request fed into the model as is, or is it preprocessed before?

Comment: You dont *have* to lowercase. You could choose to use case-insignificant comparisons and hash functions. But: it is hard to resore the needed case when generating answers. [similar for whitespace and punctuation] And: there is also POS-tagging.

Comment: Alright, but is any form of text preprocessing done on the users input, or only on the training data?

Comment: Maybe both? You cannot accept "any data", you'll at least have to tokenize it (or perform POS, or lookup, or insert, or ...)

Comment: ok, thats what I thought, but i could not find any sources on this. thanks :)